# Communicate with CMD (Tool) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I want to write a python script, that opens an *.exe-file (it is a CMD-console application)
communicates with it by sending input and reading output (for example via `stdin`, `stdout`) many times.

I tried it with `communicate()`, but it closes the pipe after I send the first input (`communicate(input='\n')`),
so it does work for me only once.

Then I tried it again via `p.stdin.readline()`, but I only can read line by line. When I read an newline, the process
terminates (that is not what I need).

I just want to start a program, read the output and send an input to it, then wait until the next output and send
a new input to it, and so on....

Is there a good way to do it? Does anybody have an example or a similar problem that is solved?

Comment: Please, include some code samples, that reproduce the problem, it's very hard to help you without them.

Comment: use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` in your Popen options.

Answer (score 0):

I need the same code as you, actually i am trying using:
 https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html 
After no sucess with subprocess..